# Dynamic continued content load with AJAX

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

What I am trying to achieve is a similar thing that most large pages do when there is a ton of content to display, but you just want to show a small portion of it and later continue loading more content (take for example the feed from Facebook, it just load the first 20 items and after scrolldown it loads the next ten or so). In my mind there are two approaches that come to mind (using PHP MySQL AJAX combination)

1. AJAX request, find all all results, return data, use data in javascript and handle logic.
2. AJAX request, find all results limit to a few, return data, users wants more data, AJAX request, find all results limit interval [few, few + few].

Maybe to clarify, the data that I want to get with the request are not really big, i just thought that reducing the number of queries is always a good idea when it comes to AJAX requests done by a user.

Both approaches do not really seem pretty and I am sure that there will be a much more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really think of any other options and actually your second option is how a lot of websites handle this sort of thing. It all depends on how much data is 'a ton of content'.

The easiest option (IMHO) is your first one, however it's pretty clear that you you have as much data as facebook it's just not feasible to fetch and store it all (imagine the page loading times!).

But afterall those are only two options: fetch it all at once, or fetch it in bits as required.

Comment: The problem that I see with the "fetch it in bits as required" is that you need to store which elements you would want to get anyway. Which means that you do the whole query again and then say 'now give me results 10-20'.

Comment: @toxicate20: You could always store some unique `id` with each fetched element (or group of elements) that can be used to establish what is the next group. I assume you're showing some kind of records, in which case you can just add `data-lastId` to your attribute (or otherwise store the value in javascript) and use that.